# Is it bad to use %x formatting in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I've been told make my string formatting consistent. I frequently write code like this

```
print(f'\nUpdate Frame: {update_frame}',
       '    x-pos: %spx' % round(self.x),
       '    y-pos: %spx' % round(self.y),
       '    x-vel: %spx/u' % round(self.vx),
       '    y-vel: %spx/u' % round(self.vy),
       sep='\n')
```

because I think it's easier to use `%x` for some things (like appending units) but it's easier to use f-strings for others. Is this bad practice?

Comment: As long as `%s` remains supported and not deprecated, from the Python only point of view it wouldn't be considered as such.  However, if writing code for another project that explicitly prohibit this style, then it would be considered "bad".  Note that this can be quite opinionated.

Comment: Told by whom? Why did you think you *should* be inconsistent? And why round instead of actually using strong formatting?

Comment: Codereview and some others have commented on it. I don't code in a professional environment, and I like `%s` probably out of habit

Comment: It's fine to use it, but there are other ways to do the same thing that you might like better or find more convenient, easier to read, &c.

Comment: I think this quesiton is primarily opinion based. What do you mean by "Is it bad?" Do you mean not as fast as it can be? Not as readable? Not as writeable? Not "pythonic" (which I feel is opinion based as well)? I don't think there's truly a way you can actually answer this question without inserting your own opinions into this. As long as you aren't doing something universally regarded as bad (for example, using %s when inserting into a sqlite database), there will be people who will argue both sides and they'll be subjectively right in their own minds.

Comment: And as I wrote that, some other people seemed to agree and put it on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** This seems to be a very primarily opinion-based question. I will provide an answer based on what I have seen within the Python community.

It is not a bad use to use `%` for formatting strings. *Some developers recommended* using f-strings and `str.format()` because doing so improves readability. In general, developers recommend using f-strings. In lower versions of python, one should use `str.format()`.

#### f-strings:

```py
    print(f'\n    Update Frame: {update_frame}',
          f'    x-pos: {round(self.x)}px' ,
          f'    y-pos: {round(self.y)}px',
          f'    x-vel: {round(self.vx)}px/u',
          f'    y-vel: {round(self.vy)}px/u',
          sep='\n')
```

#### str.format():

```py
print('\n    Update Frame: {}'.format(update_frame),
      '    x-pos: {}px'.format(round(self.x)) ,
      '    y-pos: {}px'.format(round(self.y)),
      '    x-vel: {}px/u'.format(round(self.vx)),
      '    y-vel: {}px/u'.format(round(self.vy)),
      sep='\n')
```